# JUnit/Mockito to test a class containing "code table" like static data loaded from a DB

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a Java class that contains all my code table like data; e.g. code table is called "Status" and has three values like so:

- 1 => Good
- 2 => Bad
- 3 => Ugly

Simplified it looks like this

```
public class Codes
{
    private static Map<String, Map<String, String>> CODES;
    
    public static void init(List<String> ctList) throws Exception
    {
        try (Connection con = ...)
        {
            // the SQL executed has an IN(?) where the ctList defines a list of the tables to load
            ResultSet results = prepStmt.execute();

            while(results.next())
            {
                String id = results.getString("TYP");
                String code = results.getString("CODE");
                String desc = results.getString("DESC");

                if(!CODES.containsKey(id))
                    CODES.put(id, new HashMap<>());
                
                Map<String, String> ct = CODES.get(id);
                
                ct.put(code, code);
                ct.put(desc.toUpperCase().trim(), code); // allows searching for code by description
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getCodeStr(String table, String key)
    {
        return CODES.get(table).get(key);
    }
}
```

Now inside my application I frequently refer to this class.  Simple example

```
String test = Codes.getCodeStr("test_table_id", "test_code_value");
```

When mocking I won't be able to connect to a database.  So what must I do to be able to test with this class?

One thing I have considered is collect all the code table data into a file and then initialize from the file based on some switch.  I just have to make sure the file is kept up to date...

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome but I do prefer to avoid/limit injection when I can.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid injection? One of the reasons injection is so widely used is that it helps testing the code and in this case injection (e.g. of initialization strategy) is probably the first solution that comes to mind.

Comment: I am using a strategy pattern with a container (IBM WebSphere) that does not seem to support injection for that design pattern like Spring does.  Can you point me to any documentation that shows a proper way to do what I want with Injection?  I will see if I can get it to work with what we have.

Comment: I'd start [with the Java Code Geeks article about manual dependency injection](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-manual-way.html) and see where you can go from there. If you could add an example or two of the way the `Codes` class is actually used in your code (not in the tests), it would be easier to provide a more realistic way of implementation.